# How can I see and manage all my assigned task cross-project/ cross-teams/ cross-sprints in a Board View in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

If I work as a developer, I am working on different projects/ sprints/ teams/ boards in azure devops. I would like to have a board that I could visualize all of my assigned work items from all projects, etc. How can I do this, please?

Currently, I cas see the self-assigned item through **My Work Items, how can I see them in Board?**

Thank you.

Currently, I can see the self-assigned item through **My Work Items, how can I see them in Board?**

Comment: Hi @Zacharoula Br, would you please let me know whether my suggestion below is helpful for you? Feel free to let me know if you have any question. If it's helpful, to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept my answer according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Kanban boards are associated with a team and display work items that are based on the area and iteration paths that the team selected. It doesn't support visualizing work items from different projects and different team in one window. See more info from [About Kanban boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-overview?view=azure-devops).

However, there is a third-party extension [Query Based Boards](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=realdolmen.EdTro-AzureDevOps-Extensions-QueryBasedBoards-Public) can meet your needs.

1. Create a query as the following. Be sure to check **Query across projects** and save the query.
   [image]
2. Click **Show as Board**, then you can see the page as below.
   [image]
3. Click **Settings** in the upper right corner and then select the two options shown in the image.
   [image]

   Then you can see the project filter and the team field on the work item.
   [image]